# Match certain values between two separate datasets and create new columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two datasets, df1 and df2. If the source and date value in df1, match the id and date column in df2, I would like to append two new columns 'source count' and 'source pw' creating a new dataset. The source count is created by grouping the source values and taking the sum of the 'pw' column and then taking the count of the 'role' column.

**Data**

***df1***

```
source  pw  role    leaving date 
aa      10  hello   bb      q122
aa      10  hello   bb      q122
bb      5   bye     aa      q222
bb      1   ok      aa      q322
```

***df2***

```
id  date
aa  q122
aa  q222
aa  q322
bb  q122
bb  q222
bb  q322
bb  q422
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    source count    source pw
aa  q1 22   2               20
aa  q2 22   0               0
aa  q3 22   0               0
bb  q1 22   0               0
bb  q2 22   1               5
bb  q3 22   1               1
bb  q4 22   0               0
```

***Logic***

For the source 'aa' values, we see values 10 and 10 under the 'pw' column and this has a count of 2. The source is aa and the date is q1 22. These values are then appended to df2.

**Doing**

I am first creating a dictionary to match certain values
#I am not sure if this is the correct approach...

*mapping*

```
df2['source count']=df2['aa'].map({
'q1 22':'' })
```

*Take a groupby sum* and *count*

```
a= df1.groupby(['source'])['pw'].sum()
a = df1.groupby(['source'])['role'].cumcount()
```

*append dataset*

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

I am still troubleshooting, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby()`+`agg()` for calculation then merge the result by `merge()` method:

```
df1['date']=df1['date'].str[:2]+' '+df1['date'].str[2:]
out=(df1.groupby(['source','date'])['pw'].agg(['count','sum'])
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'source':'id','count':'source count','sum':'source pw'}))
out=df2.merge(out,on=['id','date'],how='left').fillna(0,downcast='infer')
```

output of `out`:

```
    id  date    source count    source pw
0   aa  q1 22   2               20
1   aa  q2 22   0               0
2   aa  q3 22   0               0
3   bb  q1 22   0               0
4   bb  q2 22   1               5
5   bb  q3 22   1               1
6   bb  q4 22   0               0
```

Comment: Let me try this